# Delete Project Azure ML Studio ( Web App)

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

How do I delete projects in my workspace ?when I click to delete a project the delete button is inactive. Tried clearing cache and whatnot but cannot delete the project from studio.azureml.net... how do I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced your issue. Try to go to your project -> EDIT ->remove the **ASSETS** of your project. Then the delete button will be able.

You could follow the screenshot.

1. The **DELETE** button is disable.

[image]

2.Go to **EDIT** and remove the **ASSETS**.

[image]

[image]

3.Then the **DELETE** button will be able

[image]